# HTTP Ports in .NET Remoting

Tags: remoting, .net-remoting

Is there a limit to the number of HTTP ports in a machine. I have a windows application that uses .NET Remoting. Each instance of the application, exposes a Remote object on load, through a HTTP Channel with port 0 (so that port can be decided dynamically). In a Multi user environment, will there be a limit to the number of HTTP Ports.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there will be a limit to the number of ports available which is 65535 minus the number of ports already in use for existing services (for example, SMTP [25], HTTPS [443], SQL Server [1433], etc).

So on a typical Windows server, a finger in the air calculation would be 65535 - 1024 (the well know service ports <= 1024 which are considered out of bounds) - another 10-20 or so possible other application (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc). This would leave around 64490 post available.

However will you really be running 64000 of instances of your server?

Comment: No, We will need only 5000 instances. But in a Citrix environment, with 126 Virtual machines, spanned around 6 Host servers, will the Ports be specific to server or to VMs.

Comment: The ports are specific to an IP address on a host. Each and every IP address has 65535 ports available.